# iPhone 11 What are the authorized manufacturer/s for iPhone 11's Screen

Tags: iphone, screen

I have an iPhone 11, and today the screen broke when my mobile fall down.

I want to buy a new screen for my iPhone 11 from Amazon, but I am not sure which are the authorized brand(s) for iPhone 11.

Is there a resource that qualifies aftermarket parts for iPhones?

Answer (score 9):

Apple does not approve any brands for direct to consumer sale of Phone parts. They recommend complete service in an Apple Store or an AASP (Apple Authorized Service Provider Program). Parts alone don’t make the repair successful.

- https://locate.apple.com

However, it can be cheaper to replace the screen at home. Keep in mind that you won't get any Apple "free" warranty replacement after your repair. Also, True Tone will be disabled on the phone - even if you use Apple "original" or “equivalent” screens.

I recommend [iFixit parts](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/iPhone/iPhone-11-Screen/IF426-000?o=2), they come with great tools and the screen is of good quality - I ordered iPhone 11, 8 and XR screen parts without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply.. So you mean i can not buy the same screen which will get replaced if i  replace it in an Apple Store? i contacted an Apple authorized reseller and they mentioned that it need 1.5 month to get the screen and it will cost 420 USD, so i find getting the screen myself will be faster and cheaper.. but i am stucked at getting the same original screen which is originally provided in my original iPhone.. any advice please?

Comment: Correct @testtest you can not buy Apple parts, they only sell to Apple Certified shops. Apple has increased the shops that are certified by more than 10 fold in many countries, so if you get two quotes, you might be able to get the repair expedited. If someone sells you authentic parts they are lying to either you or to Apple supply chain. Something in your quote is fishy - ask them if you can call Apple to confirm your exact quote details of the quote can’t be updated. You need service pricing , not reseller pricing.

Comment: @bmike thanks for your clarification.. but can you advice more on what do u exactly mean by `ask them if you calling Apple with that quite would straighten it out.`?

Comment: Someone is not telling the story correctly. I edited my comment so hopefully it’s clearer now. 420 USD is a major repair, not a screen swap. (Heck iPhone 8 used are below $50 USD in many shops now)

Comment: You can fix true tone with some additional hardware - basically there are programmers available that will let you copy the screen serial number from your old screen to the new.